# Query Overpass Turbo for postal code boundaries

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm looking to query Overpass Turbo for postal code boundaries, specifically all within the USA. Here's what I found so far and where I'm stymied:

This [query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/ntF) for postal code boundaries in Liepzig **works**:

```
area[name="Leipzig"][admin_level=6][boundary=administrative]->.myarea;
rel(area.myarea)["boundary"="postal_code"];
out geom;
```

This [query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/ntH) for boundaries of the State of Oregon **works**:

```
area[name="Oregon"][admin_level=4][boundary=administrative]->.myarea;
rel(pivot.myarea);
out geom;
```

But this [query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/ntI) for postal code boundaries inside the State of Oregon **does not**:

```
area[name="Oregon"][admin_level=4][boundary=administrative]->.myarea;
rel(area.myarea)["boundary"="postal_code"];
out geom;
```

Thoughts on why this last query doesn't work while the first two do?

Comment: Have you reviewed this question and answer? I imagine if you found the area id for Oregon you would be successful using the query offered.
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134501/overpass-api-get-coordinates-of-postal-boundary

Comment: That is the post that helped me get the query correct for Liepzig - but the underlying data seems to not exists for most of the USA as noted by @AndreJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only get out of Openstreetmap what others have put into the database.

If you look at https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/tags/boundary=postal_code#map, you will see that boundaries of type `postal_code` are mostly used in Germany, but only few outside.

Address information is mainly stored using the key `addr:postcode`, as you see at 
https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/addr:postcode#map, as well as the key `postal_code` https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/postal_code#map. So you have to query for those, and build boundary polygons from that yourself.

You will probably run into timeout problems with Overpass, so think of downloading http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/oregon-latest.osm.pbf and filter that locally. Or take a look at [Sources for US Zip Code Boundaries?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/sources-for-us-zip-code-boundaries) or https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_zcta.html

Comment: I ended up using the moderately low resolution data provided by the census bureau:  https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-cart-boundary.html