# Finding appropriate osmfilter syntax for city, state/province, and postal code mappings for geocoding

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim, osmfilter

I have a goal of running a Nominatim instance that's capable of geocoding at the city / postal code level.

My understanding (which could be wrong since I'm pretty new to OSM data) is that I can filter the data to include only city/town, state/province, and postal code data. However, I don't think that my current filter is correct, but am having difficulty narrowing down why.

I'm currently running:

```
osmfilter.exe input.osm --keep="place=city =province =state =county =country =town =village =hamlet boundary=postal_code" -o=filtered.osm --verbose
```

What I *think* this is doing is keeping all of the cities, towns, counties, countries, villages, and hamlets -- and also keeping all of the postal code boundaries. However, when I look at the resulting data and attempt to search it for ZIP-code related entries (e.g. in the US), I'm not seeing the results that I'd expect.

What is the correct osmfilter syntax to produce a result that contains town/city, state/province, and postal code data such that I can use it to geocode at that level?

If osmfilter is no longer the ideal tool for this job, what is the best tool?

Comment: I missed this previously, but reviewing whether this answer may also apply here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/231981/232784

Comment: Looks like I'm going to have to abandon this pursuit. It seems that even with a highly filtered OSM dataset, popular tools like Nominatim and Pelias still require a ton of disk space -- which is completely fair, but pushes this into the realm of "buy" instead of "build" for my situation.